# how to connect a C programm with javascript?

Tags: javascript, c, database-design, tooltip, schema

I have a schema discovery tool programm written in C. it discovers the schema automatically. Also i have a web application written in javascript. i want to visualise the data recieved from that tool on that web application. How can i connect the both. i.e. C programm tool and javascript written web appllication?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging

Answer (score 0):

**In your C Code put the following lines**

**1 . Create a function in Javascript**

```
  parser.parse( "function faculty(input) {\n"
  "   if(input<=1) return 1;\n"
  "   return input*faculty(input-1);\n"
  "}");

context* c=parser.get_context();
```

**Call function from C++**
    valueP result = c->global()"faculty";

**Extract result (should be 3628800)**

```
int output = unwrap<int>(result)();
```

Comment: thank you. Would it also help to recieve messages(data) from that C programm (schema finder) in that javascript application?